# Standard for html5 apps and clients to negotiate input capabilities?

Tags: html, standards, w3c, web-standards, multi-touch

Practical Example:
Suppose you wrote [this html "app"](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html#mappage) and want to know if the client supports multitouch input. If it does, the buttons become expendable thus may be hidden - which is highly desirable on small screens. Of course, putting users through a multitouch capability test after installation would be an option, however that's a quirky solution.

Being aware of the current [w3c candidate recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) on touch events, and things like the app manifest (which deals only with caching requirements), i would like to ask:

- is there any standard (=non-proprietary), even as draft or recommendation for a mechanism that allows for negotiation of touch input capabilities between an app and client?
- If no - which would be the appropriate "tree to bark at", in order to spark discussion with the right organisation / people (or maybe it has been discussed before and rejected for a good reason)?

Answer (score 0):

The Device API working group would be the most appropriate venue for this discussion. Here is a listing of their work:

```
2016-10-18  Vibration API (Second Edition)  Recommendation
Nightly Draft

2015-02-10  Vibration API   Recommendation
Nightly Draft

2012-10-02  Web API Design Cookbook     Group Note

2012-07-03  Web Application Privacy Best Practices  Group Note

2011-12-01  Requirements for Home Networking Scenarios  Group Note

2011-03-17  Device API Access Control Use Cases and Requirements    Group Note

2010-06-29  Device API Privacy Requirements     Group Note

2009-10-15  Device APIs Requirements    Group Note
Drafts

2016-12-12  MediaStream Image Capture   Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-12-06  MediaStream Recording   Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-11-02  Audio Output Devices API    Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-09-13  Accelerometer Sensor    Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-09-13  Gyroscope Sensor    Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-09-13  Magnetometer Sensor     Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-08-30  Ambient Light Sensor    Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-08-30  Media Capture from DOM Elements     Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-08-30  Generic Sensor API  Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-08-03  Wake Lock API   Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-07-19  Proximity Sensor    Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-07-14  Screen Capture  Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-07-12  Media Capture Depth Stream Extensions   Working Draft
Nightly Draft

2016-07-07  Battery Status API  Candidate Recommendation
Nightly Draft

2016-05-19  Media Capture and Streams   Candidate Recommendation
Nightly Draft

2014-09-09  HTML Media Capture  Candidate Recommendation

Nightly Draft
2014-02-20  Network Service Discovery   Working Draft

Nightly Draft
2012-03-06  MediaStream Capture Scenarios   Working Draft
```

**References**

- [All Documents (sorted by group): Device and Sensors Working Group - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/tr-groups-all#tr_Device_and_Sensors_Working_Group)
- [Device API homepage](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/)
- [Device API mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-device-apis/)
- [Rule Languages for Interoperability Workshop Position Paper: Simple Common Logic](https://www.w3.org/2004/12/rules-ws/paper/103/)